# Features' confidence interval

Tags: machine-learning

I have some input feature representing a physical quantity that's measured with a given incertitude.

Is there a way to feed the information about the incertitude to, let's say, a regressor using that feature in an effective way?

Two ways I see are creating new features by adding/subtracting the incertitude or making different predictions using the measured value and the upper/lower bounds separately.
But I'm wondering if someone has a better approach up the sleeve!

Comment: You could try feeding quantiles, e.g. 5th, 25th, 50th, 75th, 95th